# Receiving some inaccurate (or no) grep matches for numbers in garbled text

Tags: regex, bash, grep, cygwin

I'm working on a coding challenge that requires my program (writing it in bash on Cygwin) to search for numbers that match different representations of valid IPv4 addresses in a garbled text. I've worked out a lot of my bugs, but I've come across a problem when dealing with some numbers. When I grep for a specific number, I'm receiving results that are within a larger number, which I don't want.

Say I have the following test text:
Dotted decimal89.229.130.225with no leading zero.
Dotted hexadecimal0xc0.0x0.0x02.0xebEach octet is individually converted to hexadecimal form.
Dotted octal0300.0000.0002.0353Each octet is individually converted into octal.
Dotted binary11000000.00000000.00000010.11101011Each octet is individually converted into binary.

10101010101010101010101010101010Binary11000000000000000000001011101011
030135300000Octal030000001353
Hexadecimal0xC00002EBConcatenation of the octets from the dotted hexadecimal.
Decimal3221226219The 32-bit number expressed in decimal.
1.1.1.1.1

I'm trying to search for a 12-digit number whose first digit is zero, second digit is [1-7], and third through 12th digits are [0-7]. I tried this grep originally:

```
grep -o '0[1-7][0-7]\{10\}'
```

But this returned:
010101010101 <- unwanted 
010101010101 <- unwanted 
030135300000  <- desired output
030000001353 <- desired output

Because I don't want to use a number that is within another number, I tried to get matches that have anything but a number before or after:

```
grep -o '[^0-9]0[1-7][0-7]\{10\}[^0-9]'
```

But this is returning nothing!

I've tried the following, also, from other related posts:

```
grep -Eo '(^|[^0-9])0[1-7][0-7]\{10\}($|[^0-9])'
grep -o '[^0-9]?0[1-7][0-7]\{10\}[^0-9]?'
grep -P '(?<!\d)0[1-7][0-7]\{10\}(?!\d)'
```

None has worked. Nothing comes out.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Obviously something's wrong with my regex/reasoning/text, but I don't know what it is! Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your last one looks promising, why escape quantifier? Try `grep -Po '(?<!\d)0[1-7][0-7]{10}(?!\d)'` and be aware that third to 12th character you're matching here `[0-7]` and not `[0-9]` you said: *and third through 12th digits are [0-9]*... Sounds more like you wanted `(?<!\d)0[1-7]\d{10}(?!\d)`

Comment: I think I had needed to use escapes because I was using basic expressions instead of extended, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm still pretty inexperienced. The [0-9] thing was a typo and is now fixed. Finally, your revision fixed my problem, but I don't know how to credit you for it! Thanks, mate.

Comment: welcome, added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last pattern looks good but don't escape the quantifier and use grep with [options](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm) `-Po`

- `-P` *--perl-regexp*   Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
- `-o` *--only-matching*   Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN

The negative [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) won't allow a match inside digits.

```
grep -Po '(?<!\d)0[1-7][0-7]{10}(?!\d)'
```

[See pcre demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xO1bY3/1)

Answer (score 0):

My version of grep responds a little bit different. I had to rewrite your first grep statement into `grep -Eo '0[1-7][0-7]{10}' input` for the same output (4 lines, 2 unwanted).

Your improvement didn't work for numbers at the start or end of the line. You can look for these as well, but your result can be 12, 13 or 14 character long. You need to grep again over the results:

```
grep -Eo '([^0-9]|^)0[1-7][0-7]{10}([^0-9]|$)' input |
   grep -Eo '0[1-7][0-7]{10}'
```

When you are OK with a second grep, you can change the approach.
First look for numbers and check your results:

```
grep -Eo "[0-7]{12}" input | grep -E "^0[1-7][0-7]{10}$"
```

With your grep this might look like

```
grep -o '[0-7]\{12}' input | grep '^0[1-7][0-7]\{10}$`
```